# Scite Lua: string comparison raises "attempt to call a string value"?

Tags: lua

Trying to write a Lua script for Scite (something like [lua-users wiki: Scite Comment Box](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SciteCommentBox)), and when I write the following piece of code:

```
fchars = string.sub(line, 1, 3)

if fchars == "//" or fchars == "##" 
  print "got it"
end
```

... the compilation fails with "`attempt to call a string value`".

I have tried different variants, such as:

```
assert(ktest = (("//" == fchars) or ("##" == fchars)))
```

... and it seems to me that compilation fails when I try to make a 'compound' boolean expression using the [logical operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#2.5.3) "`or`".

So, how would I do the above check in Lua? Maybe the C-like syntax as above is not supported at all - and I should use something like [match](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.match) instead?

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following worked fine for me:

```
line = "//thisisatest"

fchars = string.sub(line, 1, 2) -- I assume you meant 1,2 since // and ##
                                -- are only 2 characters long

if fchars == "//" or fchars == "##" then -- you're missing 'then'
   print("got it!") 
end
```

Comment: Thanks John - seems we were writing at the same time, so I missed your answer at first :) Btw, re: "1,2" - I made that mistake after reading "`substring of a string s ranging from position i to j (inclusive)`" in [Programming in Lua : 27.2](http://www.lua.org/pil/27.2.html), and remembering here the strings are 1-based :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Pfffft.... syntax error - forgot `then` at end:

```
if fchars == "//" or fchars == "##" then
  print "got it"
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: Note - this error may also occur even if you have remembered the `then`, yet you made the mistake of using say `<>` or `!=` as the not-equal relation operator, instead of the proper `~=` ( [Lua: 5.0 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html) )... A rather confusing error message, if I may add :)